# There has been an error processing your request, can't click on products

Tags: magento-1.9, error, fatal-error

I'm getting this error when I click on any product in my magento store -

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Invalid method
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array
>   ( ) )
>
> Error log record number: 747934858945

I tried these steps below, but they didn't work -

1. In the CPanel, go to File Manager and then go to the "errors" folder.
2. Rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`.
3. Go to `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend` and click "Edit" on `File.php`
4. Scroll down a bit until you see this code:

   ```
   protected $_options = array(
         'cache_dir' => 'null',
         'file_locking' => true,
         'read_control' => true,
         'read_control_type' => 'crc32',
         'hashed_directory_level' => 0,
         'hashed_directory_perm' => 0700,
         'file_name_prefix' => 'zend_cache',
         'cache_file_perm' => 0600,
         'metadatas_array_max_size' => 100
   ```

Change `null` to `tmp/` and the code will look like this -

```
protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
        'file_locking' => true,
        'read_control' => true,
        'read_control_type' => 'crc32',
        'hashed_directory_level' => 0,
        'hashed_directory_perm' => 0700,
        'file_name_prefix' => 'zend_cache',
        'cache_file_perm' => 0600,
        'metadatas_array_max_size' => 100
```

5. Go to your root directory folder and make a `tmp` folder.
6. After that refresh your page.

I did these steps but they didn't work.

Is there anything else I can do to fix the issue where clicking on any product brings me to an error page? Please give me all the steps on where to go and exactly how to locate specific files and edit certain parts of these files.